# Conectar strapi a discord

Tags: api, strapi

me gustaría saber si es posible consumir la api de discord para validad un login usando una cuenta de discord de la misma forma que en alguna plataforma es posible registrarse usando facebook o gmail, que sea posible registrase usando una cuenta de discord y que ademas se valide el si el usuario que se quiere regitrar pertenece a un servidor especifico y en caso de que no, no le permita conectarse

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: me gustaría saber si es posible consumir la api de discord para validad un login usando una cuenta de discord de la misma forma que en alguna plataforma es posible registrarse usando facebook o gmail, que sea posible registrase usando una cuenta de discord y que ademas se valide el si el usuario que se quiere regitrar pertenece a un servidor especifico y en caso de que no, no le permita conectarse